What's the Concept behind PDAs which are system Accounts?
During my study, I came across this codebase that talked about PDAs that are system accounts; What's the idea behind it? My thoughts were a Program has ownership of the PDA derived from it's Program ID
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::system_program::{ transfer, Transfer };

declare_id!("BBP3h7hBbBhGDPMPoHSzuz8hoo3NDsMtaRcXDG7Y2ssX");

#[program]
mod sys_pda_example {
    use super::*;
    pub fn transfer_to_pda(ctx: Context<Example>, fund_lamports: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let pda = &mut ctx.accounts.pda;
        let signer = &mut ctx.accounts.signer;
        let system_program = &ctx.accounts.system_program;

        let pda_balance_before = pda.get_lamports();

        transfer(
            CpiContext::new(system_program.to_account_info(), Transfer {
                from: signer.to_account_info(),
                to: pda.to_account_info(),
            }),
            fund_lamports
        )?;

        let pda_balance_after = pda.get_lamports();

        require_eq!(pda_balance_after, pda_balance_before + fund_lamports);

        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn transfer_from_pda(ctx: Context<Example>, return_lamports: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let pda = &mut ctx.accounts.pda;
        let signer = &mut ctx.accounts.signer;
        let system_program = &ctx.accounts.system_program;

        let pda_balance_before = pda.get_lamports();

        let bump = &[ctx.bumps.pda];
        let seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[b"vault".as_ref(), bump];
        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

        transfer(
            CpiContext::new(system_program.to_account_info(), Transfer {
                from: pda.to_account_info(),
                to: signer.to_account_info(),
            }).with_signer(signer_seeds),
            return_lamports
        )?;

        let pda_balance_after = pda.get_lamports();

        require_eq!(pda_balance_after, pda_balance_before - return_lamports);

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Example<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"vault".as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub pda: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


System Account is just a name given to the PDA account.
PDA accounts are owned by the program that derived them.
The name for System account might come from the fact that they are holding lamports and not data and because they interact with system program.

but they weren't derived from the system's program id; so how are they system account? that's the confusion? how does that even work?

The idea is that a PDA (Program Derived Address) is a system account owned and controlled by a program, allowing it to securely store and manage funds or data in a deterministic and trustless manner.
